# Java servlet and JSP accessing the same session bean

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Let's say I have a simple Login servlet that checks the passed `name` and creates `User` object and stores it in a session.

```
User user = new User();
user.setId(name);

request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

In the `index.jsp` page I access the user object through `jsp:useBean`

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session"
             class="package.name.User"/>

<div class="panel">
    Welcome ${user.id}
</div>
```

It works so far.

From the jsp beans documentation

> To locate or instantiate the Bean,
>    takes the following
>   steps, in this order:
>
> 1. Attempts to locate a Bean with the scope and name you specify.
> 2. Defines an object reference variable with the name you specify.
> 3. If it finds the Bean, stores a reference to it in the variable. If
>      you specified type, gives the Bean
>      that type.
> 4. If it does not find the Bean, instantiates it from the class you
>      specify, storing a reference to it in
>      the new variable. If the class name
>      represents a serialized template, the
>      Bean is instantiated by
>      java.beans.Beans.instantiate.
> 5. If  has instantiated (rather than located) the Bean, and if
>      it has body tags or elements (between
>       and ),
>      executes the body tags.

**The questions:**

> Attempts to locate a Bean with the scope and name you specify

It does not specify the "locate" process. Does it mean it will check `HttpServletRequest.getSession()` or just check whether other pages already created this bean or not?

> If it does not find the Bean, instantiates it from the class you specify, storing a > reference to it in the new variable.

This actually means that Jsp can associate a newly created bean with session using **jsp_internal_name_user**.
There is no word about how Jsp stores and finds beans in the session.

There is an option to access session objects by using `${sessionScope.user}` and that will guarantee that "user" from the Java session object will be get. The same one I put into by myself.

Java EE 5 example "Book Store" access session objects using `${sessionScope.name}` approach.

Using just `${user}` works. And this is what worries me. I would like to see a specific sentence in the specification about the `locate` process and whether `${user}` must work or whether it is up to the JSP and/or JSTL reference implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of a controller (servlet) which takes care about the model, the `jsp:useBean` is only useful if the default instance (constructed with the no-arg constructor) exposes different behavior/state than a non-existing instance. E.g. if you would like to have a default user name "Unknown User", you would do:

```
public User {
    this.id = "Unknown User";
}
```

Else the enduser may face a "Welcome" instead of "Welcome Unknown User" display. In your particular case, you can safely remove it. It's superfluous.

However, I've also seen the argument that it's useful for pure documentation. You could declare "useless" `jsp:useBean` instances in top of JSP page so that you have an overview which models exactly are been used in the particular JSP page. Although I find it pretty smart, I myself have never had the need for this way of documenting the model in JSP. As per the comments, another argument is indeed that this way IDE's like IDEA and Eclipse are able to autocomplete bean properties in EL.

**Update**: as to the locating, it uses [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) for that and then uses reflection/javabean introspection to invoke getter methods on it. E.g.

```
${user.name}
```

roughly resolves to

```
out.print(pageContext.findAttribute("user").getName())
```

Also see the [JSP specification](https://jsp.dev.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec.pdf) and the [JSP EL specification](https://jsp.dev.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf).

**Update 2**: the `<jsp:useBean>` ***certainly*** doesn't use an internal name or so as session attribute prefix. Loop over all session attributes yourself to see the actual keys and values:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope}" var="entry">
    ${entry.key} = ${entry.value}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

or in a servlet

```
for (String name : Collections.list(session.getAttributeNames())) {
   System.out.println(name + " = " + session.getAttribute(name));
}
```

Comment: Is there some documentation which explicitly describe the process of the variables resolving in a jsp page?

Comment: Intellij IDEA completes variable fields only in case of the explicit declaration.

Comment: 1) You're talking about EL? Check the [JSP EL specification](https://jsp.dev.java.net/spec/jsp-2_1-fr-spec-el.pdf). In a nutshell, it does `PageContext#findAttribute()` to locate attributes in any scope. 2) That's indeed also another argument I've seen before.

Comment: Thanks for pointing things out. I was referring JSP spec and did not find anything useful there. Looking in EL Spec.

Comment: Could you please point to section where you have found "roughly resolves to..."?

Comment: Well, it's in brain cell # 1875129. No, sorry I'm more telling from >7 years JSP/Servlet experience and knowing how it works "under the hoods". The above example is one which makes the most sense to the JSP/EL-unaware. The EL spec is a bit more abstract than that. `ELResolver` and so on. But the straightforward way (what practically all EL implementers --Sun, Apache, JBoss, etc-- do) is to start with `PageContext#findAttribute()` to find the attribute by name in any of the scopes and then go ahead with resolving using reflection/introspection/etc.

Comment: So, the usage of the session bean in my question's example is valid?

Comment: It's functionally and technically valid, yes. But it's technically superfluous.

Comment: I am sorry I still ask questions. But just noticed that even BookStore EE5 example is using "sessionScope.cart" instead of just "cart"

Comment: Check http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnahw. As to the bookstore example, it's just an *explicit* reference to ensure that it doesn't return a "coincidental" `cart` instance in page or request scope (which are scanned *before* the session scope). This is just a "practice", but not necessary.

Comment: I accidentally put plus again on the answer and it became "score remove" action. I edit your answer just to be able to put scores back. Please undo my changes. Thanks very much for pointing to the text. I was looking in the specs and it was just on the tutorial page.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the JSP spec JSP.5.1

> The basic semantic tries to find an existing object using id and
>   scope. If the object is not found it will attempt to create the object using the other
>   attributes.

In other words,

```
<jsp:useBean id="user" scope="session" class="package.name.User"/>
```

would translate roughly into java as:

```
package.name.User user = (package.name.User)session.getAttribute("user");
if (user == null){
  user = new package.name.User();
  session.setAttribute("user", user);
}
```

Comment: Hey, glad to see you here :) Your answer is indeed right for the particular `jsp:usebean` line, you only forgot the `session.setAttribute("user", user);` in the `if` block ;)

Comment: I would like to see the description of "find an existing" process. In fact jsp can store object using "user_jsp_internal" name.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The object is stored with the attribute key as specified in `id`. How else would you be able to access it in plain EL by `${user}` and so on?

Comment: Because of the current implementation. Why then we have ${scopeSession.user} explicit expression available to use. Please point where did you find that it will store it in the session by using id? I think it is what JSR implementation guys can decide themselves.

Comment: Refer to JSP.5.1.
It is all there in black and white.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> The `<jsp:useBean>` element locates or instantiates a JavaBeans component.
>   `<jsp:useBean>` first attempts to locate an instance of the Bean.
>   If the Bean does not exist, `<jsp:useBean>` instantiates it from a class or serialized
>   template.

Since "locating" the bean is perfectly allright then we can assume that the bean may be made available by means other than instantiation via `<jsp:useBean>`. For instance, by creating it in a servlet.